# How can i set timer in iPhoneGame app?

Tags: iphone

i have an game application.I want to set a timer from the beginning upto end.Can any one tell me how to set timer on iphone app?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourmethod)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

try this 
or read more about NSTimer class

Comment: what is the yourmethod here?what did you mean?i want to start a timer at the startup and show it in a label upto the ending..